# Bubble sort implementation in C++

Tags: c++, sorting

I was wondering if this implementation of bubble sort could be improved. Are there any things that I have done wrong?

```
template<typename Element>
void bubble_sort(Element arr[], size_t size) {
    auto sorted_elements = 1u;
    bool sorted = false;
    while (!sorted) {
        sorted = true;
        for (auto index = 0u; index < size - sorted_elements; ++index) {
            if (arr[index] > arr[index + 1]) {
                auto temp = arr[index + 1];
                arr[index + 1] = arr[index];
                arr[index] = temp;
                sorted = false;
            }
        }
        ++sorted_elements;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Implementation

- `size - sorted_elements` might not return what you expect if `size == 0` (it returns `std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max()`). This makes the intended check fail for `size == 0`. This can be fixed by changing the while loops condition to `sorted_elements < size && !sorted`.
- You could use `std::swap(arr[index], arr[index + 1]);` to swap the elements. This way, the preferred assignment operation (copy or move) for `Element` will be used (if `Element` provides its own specialization). Currently, you always copy, which might not always be preferred (e.g. with large `std::string`s).

Comment: Yes you are right I get a runtime error if the size is 0. I did not think about it. Thanks!

Comment: @puls99: unsigned and floating point comparisons are always suspect and should be double checked. There are many subtle bugs hidden this way